# Passing params to another component angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I navigate to another component e.g. (dashboard) and would like to pass a data params to this component.
Now, I put my params here:
router.navigate(['/dashboard', {data: some string}]);
. But here router put in address link my data. How can I pass params without putting it in address link.

Comment: Use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Here, I haven't parent or child component. I have 2 component. Index and Dashboard. After e.g. login I navigate to dashboard with these code:router.navigate(['/dashboard', {data: some string}]);

Comment: Then please read more than the first paragraph from the link I posted ;-)